# Inserting items into an empty array

Tags: arrays, swift, swift2

I am not completely sure if this is possible.. I am starting off with an empty array. I have a tableview each with different numbers. When the user clicks on a cell, the selected number is appended into the array.

Now, the problem I am facing is that the user can click on any cell in any order, but I need my array to be ordered so that cell 1 matches with index 1, cell 2 matches with index 2 and so on.

What I have tried so far is append. but this inserts numbers out of order. I have tried insert, but this throws an error after the first selection stating the index is out of range.

edit:

I have a tableView with numbers in numerical order: 1, 2 , 3 , 4 ... The user clicks on a number and that number is appended to the array.

The user can select any number in any order, for example: 1, 3 , 4 , 2 .. And I would end up with an array of [1,3,4,2]. I need the numbers to be ordered so that if the user were to select 3, it would end up in the third index of the array.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please post your code. Also not sure I understand the question here. Are you trying to get a count on the number of time a cell is clicked?

Comment: Your question is pretty confusing right now. Post some code please, so we can understand what you're asking.

Comment: I have a `tableView` with numbers in numerical order: 1, 2 , 3 , 4 ... The user clicks on a number and that number is appended to the array.

Comment: The user can select any number in any order, for example: 1, 3 , 4 , 2 .. And  I would end up with an array of [1,3,4,2]. I need the numbers to be ordered so that if the user were to select 3, it would end up in the third index of the array.

Comment: What if the user taps the cell with number `2` multiple times? Do you want the values in the array to be unique?

Comment: I need each value to be unique

Comment: Then what if the user clicked the cells in this order: 1 -> 4? Do you still want the array to be `[1, 4]` or `[1, nil, nil, 4]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure how you're going to use your array, but I wouldn't recommend using your own answer.

Instead of creating a fixed sized array you could use a `Dictionary`:

```
var dict: [Int: Int] = [:]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    dict[indexPath.row +1] = indexPath.row + 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array`'s `append` and `sort` functions should work just fine for what you've described:

```
// Use `var`, not `let` - you're going to change this value over time!
var tappedNumbers: [Int] = []

// You can then append numbers in order, like this:
tappedNumbers.append(2)
tappedNumbers.append(5)
tappedNumbers.append(1)

tappedNumbers.sort() // this returns the array [1, 2, 5]


// If you don't want duplicates, try using Set instead of Array:
var tappedSet: Set<Int> = []
tappedSet.insert(2)
tappedSet.insert(5)
tappedSet.insert(1) 
tappedSet.insert(5) // see, we're double-inserting 5 here...

tappedSet.count // returns 3, because there are only 3 unique entries

tappedSet.sort() // returns [1, 2, 5]
```

Drop this code into a Swift Playground and try it yourself - is this what you're describing?

Comment: I think the OP wanted the array index to be the same as the cell index, if so my answer is what the OP wanted I think

Comment: I cannot understand why that would be desirable or necessary - but, ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

You could try starting out with an array of `NSNull` objects that is the same size as the number of rows in your table view. Then as the user selects the rows, replace the `NSNull` at that index with the selected number.

`NSNull`: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNull_Class/

Comment: to create an array of `NSNull` that is the same size as the number of rows, would I do: `[NSNull, NSNull, NSNull, NSNull]`... assuming my tableview has 4 rows

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you're asking for is a way to link the cell's index with the value of the cell, here's what you should do. Don't use the value of the cell's position in the array as what the cell index is, instead use a dictionary or array of tuples containing both the cell index and the cell value. Here's an example:

```
var myDict = Dictionary<Int,Int>()

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let cellvalue = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!.textLabel!.text
    myDict.append((index: indexPath.row, value: cell value))

}
```

or with tuple:

```
typealias myTuple = (index: Int, value: Int)
var myTupleArray = Array<myTuple>()

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let cellvalue = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!.textLabel!.text
    myDict.append((index: indexPath.row, value: cell value))

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for the answer.. The code below will create an array with 4 `nil` placeholders.

`var array = [Int?](count: 4, repeatedValue: nil)`

to get the selected item at the correct index I used

`array[indexPath.row] = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!.textLabel!.text`

Comment: I agree repeating nil is not smart.. Instead I am choosing to repeat 0

Comment: Depending on how you want to use your array, maybe my answer is better. (It's more safe anyway)

Comment: I think @Eendje has the best answer here, because what you really want is a key-value relationship, not an ordered collection. BTW, you should not do `cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!` because that method sometimes returns `nil` (for example, if the cell is not visible) and it will make your app crash.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with @bryanjclark.

I'm not sure that creating an array filled with 'nil' (as you suggest in your own answer) is the ideal solution.

Again, as @bryanjclark suggests, I would use `Set`.

```
var indexSet:Set<Int> = []

// click on index 1
indexSet.insert(1)
// click on index 5
indexSet.insert(5)

// get all clicked cell indexes back in order
let sortedIndexes = indexSet.sort()

// check if a index is in the clicked set
if indexSet.contains(3) {
    print("contains")
} else {
    print("does not contain")
}
```

Comment: It seems like he wants the value to correspond with the index path, e.g. `[1, nil, nil, 4]`.

Comment: This may be what he wants, but I'm not sure it is the correct way to code it.  What if there are 10,000 cells in the table view? Should the array contain 10,000 `nil` values?  Perhaps using sets can achieve the same outcome - and for someone (presumably) new to Swift - perhaps it's good to challenge their assumptions.

Comment: Thats what a dictionary is for ;)

Comment: Although, here we are just storing a `key`, not a `key` and `value` ;)

Comment: True, but if he wants to check if the user has pressed `2` and uses `print(indexSet[2])` it might return unwanted results (it could be `2`, `3` or `4`).

Comment: As in my answer, he could simply check by using `indexSet.contains(2)` which gives a `Bool`.  The point is not to argue over `Dictionary` vs `Set` vs `Array`, but to get an apparent Swift newbie to consider other options (which I see you have done with `Dictionary` since my answer was posted).  So I think we both agree that there is a better solution than the OP provided.

Comment: I'm not criticizing your answer and what you said is true, but only if the answers are equivalent of each other. **If** he indeed wants to iterate over the array to check which cells has been tapped, your's won't work. (example: `for index in tableViewData { print(indexSet[index]) }` will either crash or might have unwanted results. Of course you can use other statements to check and get the same results (eventually) but that's not what he asked for ;).